# Using a self-sign certificate for intranet applications

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, ssl-certificate, self-signed

I'm designing a C# server-client applications communicating over an intranet using a WebApi, and I've been looking around for a way of encrypting my communication. I figured out that I can use a self-sign certificate for my needs. My question is that- Is it possible to import the certificate on the client side in the process of program installation? I want to create some kind of automation around that so I wouldn't need to do it manually every time I install a new client.

P.S - this is my first question in stack overflow so if you think I should have give more information I'll be happy to do so

Comment: Do you have an Active Directory? Then you can simply share the certificate with GPOs.

Comment: Or https://letsencrypt.org for a free trusted cert out of the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is **yes** or **no** depending on whether the **Private Key** property was marked as exportable during creation. Since it is a self-signed certificate, most of the tools that are used for creating one always have this property enabled. So you should be able to export the certificate along with the private key from the source machine in the **.pfx**  extension and then import this certificate file on the destination machine.

I am assuming you are not worried about the certificate trust as you are using a self-signed certificate.

**UPDATE**

In order to import the certificate via MMC, refer the instructions available here: [Export a certificate with private key](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754329(v=ws.11).aspx)

You can use **[certmgr.exe](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732061(v=ws.10).aspx)** or **[certutil.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732443.aspx)** to import the certificate via command line. See this:

Similaryly for **PowerShell** you can use the **`Import-Certificate`** commandlet. See this article for reference:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/powershell/windows/pkiclient/import-certificate

Also see this thread: [Import Certificate to Trusted Root but not to Personal [Command Line]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23869177/import-certificate-to-trusted-root-but-not-to-personal-command-line)

Comment: thank you for your answer. I do have the private key **.pfk**  file. so I understand from your answer that I can import the certificate automatically- but I also wanted to know what approach should I use in order to do so.

Comment: There are several approach to export the certificate file. I will add the details in the answer.

Comment: Thank you again, but I think I wasn't clear enough...
My main goal is to import the certificate on the client side programmatically - without using the windows GUI like MMC etc... 
So I have my .pfk file and I want to install my program on the client side, and in the installation process run some code/command line tools to automatically import the included certificate to the user personal certificate store.